# How to hide keyboard without animation (or speed up this animation)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, keyboard, uikeyboard

I have in my app Navigation Controller and Tool Bar. In Tool Bar is Bar Item which through action "show detail" shows Table View Controller. When I click on cancel and  this Table View is closed, but keyboard waits until Table View Controller is completely closed. I'd like to close keyboard together with Table View.

This is my Action for Cancel button:

```
@IBAction func cancelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.nameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    self.caffeineTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making textfields FirstResponder so keybord will stay open. you should resignfirstResponder from these. Other great solution for someting to close keyboard is:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [[self view] endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: Your solution works grat, I'll use it. Also resignFirstResponder works. Thank you very much

self.view.endEditing(true)

Comment: i am not similar to swift but you can find touchesBegan event for it too. Basicly when you click anywhere out of textfield it close keybord.

Comment: I used tap gesture recognizer connected to whole View to achieve this effect :)